# Android App crash java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, crash

In a newly published game (android) that utilises a remote database to get data, I get daily many app crashes reports that I cannot reproduce or i have not encountered in my tests over several real devices and virtual devices.
The top crash report is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
  (ActivityThread.java:2805)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:2883)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)

 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1613)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)

 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6523)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:438)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:857)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 

  at com.my.app.activity.LevelActivity.onCreate (LevelActivity.java:82)

  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7023)

  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7014)

   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate 
(Instrumentation.java:1214)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:2758)
```

for example the LevelActivity.java:82 :

```
        levelNo = MainActivity.dbHelper.GetLevelById(Constant.CATE_ID, Constant.SUB_CAT_ID);
```

and the oncreate until line with the NPE:

```
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);
    Utils.transparentStatusAndNavigation(LevelActivity.this);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.select_level);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });



    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(LevelActivity.this));
    levelNo = MainActivity.dbHelper.GetLevelById(Constant.CATE_ID, Constant.SUB_CAT_ID);
```

i don't know where to begin since I have never encountered this error or similar crash

All crashes related to this app are: java.lang.NullPointerException

this is not a duplicate question as the methods described in the proposed original question do not apply here.

I cannot reproduce the error, how can I debug?

Not all headaches can dissapear with aspirin

Comment: It tells you exactly what line that NPE occurs on. My suspicion is that you're assuming that fields have been initialized but they're getting cleared when Android discards and then restarts your app.

Comment: Yes I included the line in my question (82) and     private static int levelNo = 1; is declared at line 45 line